# What is this algorithm computing and how to prove it?

Tags: factoring

On [Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/) I found a test that asks to check what the following algorithm computes:

1. If $x > y$ then $x = x - y$
2. If $y > x$ then $y = y - x$
3. If $x \neq y$ then goto 1
4. Print $x$

Constraints: $x$ and $y$ are greater than $0$

So I think/guess this algorithm returns the product of common factors, so 1 when they do not have any in common. I just guessed it by computation and by intuition, but I would like to prove it in a formal way.

How can this be proved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The algorithm computes the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor), or gcd for short.
You are correct that the output is the product of common factors, since the gcd is known to be equivalent to it.

In fact, this algorithm is known as [Euclid's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Euclid%27s_algorithm).

Comment: gcd is the greatest common divisor. What do you mean "the product of common factors"? It should be the greatest of the common factors

Comment: It is the largest number dividing both $x$ and $y$. If you write $x=p_1^{r_1}\dots p_k^{r_k}\cdot q_1^{i_1}\dots q_m^{i_m}$, and write $y=p_1^{e_1}\dots p_k^{e_k} \cdot t_1^{j_1}\dots t_n^{j_n}$ then $gcd(x,y)=p_1^{\min(r_1,e_1)}\dots p_k^{\min(r_k, e_k)}$. So in some sense, it is the multiple of all common prime factors (with respect also to their exponent)